# Nicaraguan citizen with a layover at Pu Dong, Shanghai, China, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, chicago, china-airlines, nicaraguan-citizens, taipei

I cannot find an affordable flight from Taiwan to Chicago except for one about $625 through China Eastern Airline. Instead of it going Taipei direct to US (LA or San Francisco) then on to Chicago, it goes to Shanghai (PuDong) & has about a 18 hour layover there.

Any experience with this route, airline, or Pu Dong airport? Is a transit Visa needed? This is for a citizen of Nicaragua who is studying in Taiwan and got a 1 year B1/B2 US Tourist Visa wanting to visit family in the US for about 2-1/2 months & return to Taiwan for studies.

Comment: You would definitely need a visa for China. If you can find a flight through [South Korea, Philippines, or even Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Nicaraguan_citizens), you would not need a visa as a Nicaraguan citizen.

Comment: Thank you. On further research I see there appears to be a 24 hour Visa-free allowance in China if one has proof of onward travel within 24 hours of arrival and also has the appropriate Visa for their final destination. A Nicaraguan citizen doesn't seem to be restricted from that according to this link:  https://www.trip-advisor.com/Travel-g294211-c188665/China:Visa.Free.Transits.html.

Comment: How about flying via Hong Kong? I have flown from both Taipei and Kaohsiung regular to transfer there. (Not to Chicago though)

Comment: @GregHewgill OP needs a visa to *enter* the ROC or PRC, but not to transit PEK as detailed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need a transit visa** as a Nicaraguan transiting Shanghai Pudong en route to Taipei:

> / 14APR16 / 1550 UTC
>
> National Nicaragua (NI)   
>       
> Transit China (People's Rep.) (CN)
> Destination Chinese Taipei (TW)
>
> China (People's Rep.) (CN)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward airline
> tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours

Source: [Timaticweb](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=NI&TR=PVG&DE=TPE&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)

The same holds for travel in the opposite direction: [Timaticweb reference](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=NI&TR=PVG&DE=ORD&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)

Comment: Thanks - glad for more confirmation as tickets already purchased with layover in Pudong - max 6 hrs.